# Class of operators preserving the norm of shifted square-integrable functions

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a continuous and linear operator from $L_2(\mathbb{R})$ to itself.
We assume morever that, for any function $f \in L_2(\mathbb{R})$ and any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have
\begin{equation}
\lVert \mathcal{L} \{ f (\cdot - x) \} \rVert_{L_2} = \lVert \mathcal{L} \{ f \} \rVert_{L_2}. 
\end{equation}

My goal is to understand the class of such operators. For instance, we easily see that the relation above is satisfied if $\mathcal{L} f = h * f$ is a convolution since $$\lVert h * (f(\cdot - x)) \rVert_{L_2} =  \lVert (h*f) (\cdot - x)  \rVert_{L_2} = \lVert h*f \rVert_{L_2}.$$
My question is: Are the convolutions the only operators  for which the relation is satisfied?